# How to use Concatenate to append strings in google sheet?

Tags: concatenation, space

I need to put address, city, State and postcode with space in between into one cell in google sheet.

Comment: Ok, what did you try so far? Any code to share ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ", B1," ", C1, " ", D1)
```

A1 : Address

B1 : City

C1 : State

D1 : postcode

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation that tells as how to use functions ;-)

https://www.howtogeek.com/447559/how-to-concatenate-data-from-multiple-cells-in-google-sheets/